# Restore multiple Analysis DB's from windows explorer with Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, ssas, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to maken a PS script that retores multiple Analisys DB's to SSAS from windows explorer.

Here are de DB's F:\Backup\SSAS\SQL002\ xx.abf and yy.abf and many more.
And the sript that i use is this:

```
$SQLInstanceName = "SQL002"
\#$DatabaseName = Get-ChildItem $BackupFilePath -Filter \*.abf -Recurse
$DatabaseName = "DBC_tst__yesterday"
$BackupFilePath = "\\localhost\\F$\\Backup\\SSAS\\SQL002"

## Add the AMO namespace

$loadInfo = \[System.Reflection.Assembly\]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") | Out-Null
\[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server\]$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($SQLInstanceName)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
Write-Output ("Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName)
break
}

# Lets restore using the default locations

\#If ($BackupFilePath -match '.abf') { $File = $BackupFilePath }
$File = (Get-ChildItem $BackupFilePath -Filter \*.abf -Recurse| Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select           -First 1).Fullname
Write-Host "File Variable contains " $File
Write-Host "Restoring $File on $SQLInstanceName"
$Server.restore($File, $DatabaseName, $true, $null)

if ($?) {"Successfully Restore " + $DatabaseName + " to " + $SQLInstanceName }
else {"Failed to Restore " + $DatabaseName + " to " + $SQLInstanceName }
$server.Disconnect()
```

It only restores 1 db, how do i get it done that it restore als db's in de directory?
I tried already with an other variable. But that didn't work.

Thank you in advanced.

### The result of my script is that it restores only 1 db.

I modified the script. but doesn't still work. I even do not get a error anymore.

```
$BackupFilePath = "F:\Backup\SSAS\SQL002\"
$SQLInstanceName = "SQL002"
$DatabaseName = "DBC_tst__yesterday"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $BackupFilePath -Filter -File -Recurse
foreach($File in $Files)
{
Write-Host "File Variable contains " $File.Name
Write-Host "Restoring $File on $SQLInstanceName"

$Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$Server.Connect($SQLInstanceName)

$Server.restore($File.Fullname, $DatabaseName, $true, $null)

if ($?) {"Successfully Restore " + $DatabaseName + " to " + 
$SQLInstanceName }
else {"Failed to Restore " + $DatabaseName + " to " + $SQLInstanceName }
$server.Disconnect()
 }
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$BackupFilePath = "\\localhost\\F$\\Backup\\SSAS\\SQL002"
$SQLInstanceName = "SQL002"
$DatabaseName = "DBC_tst__yesterday"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $BackupFilePath -Filter \*.abf -Recurse -File
foreach($File in $Files)
{
   Write-Host "File Variable contains " $File.Fullname
   Write-Host "Restoring $File on $SQLInstanceName"
   $Server.restore($File.Fullname, $DatabaseName, $true, $null)

   if ($?) {"Successfully Restore " + $DatabaseName + " to " + $SQLInstanceName }
   else {"Failed to Restore " + $DatabaseName + " to " + $SQLInstanceName }
}
$server.Disconnect()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but this didn't do the trick.
The following error occured:
At D:\Script\Untitled7.ps1:4 char:63
+ $Files = Get-ChildItem $BackupFilePath -Filter \*.abf -Recurse)
+                                                               ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: I f forgot to remove the parenthesis that wasn't needed.

Comment: still a error:
Get-ChildItem : Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.
Parameter name: path2
At D:\Script\Untitled7.ps1:4 char:10
+ $Files = Get-ChildItem $BackupFilePath -Filter \*.abf -Recurse
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (F:\Backup\SSAS\SQL002\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : dirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Comment: Change $File.Name to $File.Fullname  Error seem to be the file name is a directory : F:\Backup\SSAS\SQL002\:String  So I think you need to add -File to ChildItem to only get files.

Comment: Still no result. PLease see my new modified script

Comment: Are you getting any output?  You should get an output for each file.  Make sure you see all the files.  You only need to connect to server once.  So I would put the connect before for loop and then disconnect after for loop.  Using SQL Server Management Studio you can check log file in the explorer under Management.  This should show a connection to Database and then any failures.